# Why do I have different kernel versions on same distribution version

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kernel, lts, mythbuntu

I  [(re)installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282119/alsa-fails-to-recognize-on-board-audio-card) Mythbuntu 12.04.2 to solve an audio problem.  After the installation I find that the kernel version of this MythTV front-end is **3.5.0-27-generic**.

However on the fully-updated Mytbuntu 12.04… Front-end/Back-end server (Installed as 12.04.1), the kernel version is **3.2.0-40-generic**.

Why are these different version, I wonder…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is explained in the [release notes for Precise](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#PrecisePangolin.2BAC8-ReleaseNotes.2BAC8-CommonInfrastructure-1.Kernel):

> By default, the 12.04.2 point release will ship with a newer
>   3.5.0-23.35 Ubuntu kernel from Quantal, and a matching X.org stack. This is based on the 3.5.7.2 Extended Upstream Stable Kernel
>   Release...The purpose of providing a newer kernel in the 12.04.2 point
>   release is for hardware enablement.

This only applies to Ubuntu, Edubuntu, and Mythbuntu.

In short, you get the newer kernel if you *install* from `12.04.02`; but keep the older kernel if you *update* `12.04.01`, unless you take steps to enable the update.

For more information on how to do that and various policies and procedures on this issue, see [LTS Enablement Stacks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

From the above link:

> Anyone wishing to opt into the hardware enablement stack for Precise
>   may do so by installing the linux-generic-lts- and
>   xserver-xorg-lts- packages.
>
> For example to install the Quantal hardware enablement packages in
>   Precise, please run the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal
> ```
>
> libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal
>
> To install the Raring hardware enablement packages in Precise, please
>   run instead the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring
> ```

See the above link for additional specifics regarding the exact policies and procedures regarding the support, maintenance, and upgrade paths for these hardware enablement stacks.

The support schedule for the kernels is given at the [Version Matrix](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/ExtendedStable)

Comment: `unless you take steps to enable the update` - what are those?

Comment: @PraveenSripati I added the instructions from the linked page. Be sure to look at that page for additional info.