# How to get kernel versions to match in a server and clients?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kernel, lts, versions

Ubuntu has released 12.04.2 LTS, which has a newer kernel than the one that comes with 12.04.1 LTS.

I prefer to keep server and clients with the same kernel version.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple, actually.  Just run...

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal
```

and both kernel and X stack will be upgraded.

Note: this upgrade worked fine on a simple HTPC running Mythbuntu, but on a older client that had been originally a 10.4 system, it was severly broken.  Might be a good idea to back-up your system before trying this.

Ubuntu calls it "LTS Hardware Enablement Stack", some details [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#LTS_Hardware_Enablement_Stack)  as referenced [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#PrecisePangolin.2BAC8-ReleaseNotes.2BAC8-CommonInfrastructure-1.Kernel).

It didn`t take very long for me but I have high speed internet service.

Thanks to *[chaskes](https://askubuntu.com/users/117123/chaskes)* for the explanation.